# sql query output to shell variable

Tags: oracle, shell

I am assigning the count from a sql query to a shell variable. But there seems to be some other blank spaces coming up.

```
output=$(
  $ORACLEHOME/bin/sqlplus -s $DBUSER/$DBPASSWORD <<EOF
   set pages 0 feed off echo off

   SELECT COUNT(1) 
            FROM TABLE_NAME
            exit;
EOF
)

echo "output is $output"

echo "length of output is ${#output}"
```

the length should be coming as 1. But it is coming as 3. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Post the output of your `db query` alone  in the question please. Also post the output.

Comment: This is the output.                                                                                                       output is        0
length of output is 3                                                                                                          The table has no records. So it should return '0'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is a neat way to do the query and assign the results to a variables. Actually there is no question here.. The `sql` output may be formatted and I assume that to have spaces in the beginning. You can either modify your sql query to print raw results- which I think is the best option- or do

```
output=${output##*[[:space:]]}
```

before calculating its length. If the variable has spaces in its beginning and end, then you may do

```
output=${output//[[:space:]]/}
```

Comment: @GourabSengupta : You're welcome, but try  modifying the query to print the count in the raw format. That would be the best way to do it I guess :)